# Loading list box Items in Text file using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, printing, listbox, alignment

Regards every coder
I am developing a program in which i need to select some items from a list box and by clicking a button i am saving the selected items along with the rate of items in an access database and simultaneously loading the same in a text file for printing purposes. Everything is working just fine except that the alignment of the items is not proper.
[The Investigations and rate are not properly aligned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CitJH.jpg)

The code which i have written as :

```
Static total As Integer
    Dim query As String
    Dim l_index As Integer
    If ListBox2.Items.Count > 15 Then
        MsgBox("Maximum 15 Investigations can be selected.",     vbInformation, "New receipt...")
        ListBox2.Items.Clear()
        Exit Sub          ElseIf txtopd.Text.Trim = "" Or txtname.Text.Trim = "" Or ListBox2.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox("Please fill all the fields", vbInformation, "New Receipt...")
        txtopd.Focus()
        Exit Sub
    Else
        '--------------------
        Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
        file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("text.txt", False)
        file.Write("Date" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
        file.Write(lbldate.Text)
        file.WriteLine()
        file.Write("Time" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
        file.Write(lbltime.Text)
        file.WriteLine()
        file.Write("Receipt#" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
        file.Write(txtreceiptno.Text)
        file.WriteLine()
        file.Write("OPD#" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
        file.Write(txtopd.Text)
        file.WriteLine()
        file.Write("Name" & vbTab & vbTab & vbTab)
        file.Write(txtname.Text)
        file.WriteLine()
        file.Write("______________________________________")
        file.WriteLine()
        Con.Open()
        For l_index = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
            query = ("select  Investigation.rate " & _
                    "from Investigation WHERE (((Investigation.Investigation) = '" & ListBox2.Items(l_index) & "'));")
            Dim cmd2 As New OleDbCommand(query, Con)
            'Con.Open()
            Dim reader As OleDbDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader
            reader.Read()
            'file.WriteLine(reader(0))
            txtrate.Text = reader.GetString(0)
            total = total + txtrate.Text
            'reader.Close()
            'Con.Close()
            ' Con.Close()
            'End If
            Dim SqlString As String = "Insert Into patients (Receipt_No, OPD_MRD,Patientname,Investigation,Receipt_date,Receipt_time,rate) Values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
            Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(SqlString, Con)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Receipt_No", txtreceiptno.Text.Trim())
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("OPD_MRD", txtopd.Text.Trim())
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Patientname", txtname.Text.Trim())
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Investigation", CStr(ListBox2.Items(l_index)).ToString())
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Receipt_date", lbldate.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Receipt_time", lbltime.Text)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("rate", txtrate.Text.Trim())
            'Con.Open()
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()                            file.Write(ListBox2.Items(l_index).ToString().PadRight(50))
            file.Write(txtrate.Text)
            file.WriteLine()
        Next
        Con.Close()
        file.Write("______________________________________")
        file.WriteLine()
        file.Write("Total Amount =" & vbTab & vbTab)
        file.Write(total)
        file.Close()
    End If

    'printing starts here
    '-----------------------------------

    Dim p As New Process
    Dim info As New ProcessStartInfo
    info.FileName = "text.txt"
    info.Verb = "print"
    p.StartInfo = info
    p.Start()
    '-----------------------------
```

Replies will be highly appreciated.
Thank you

Comment: What test output looks like depends on heavily on the font used. If you expect to have lines of text aligned based on characters in that text then you have no chance unless you use a fixed-width font. Instead of using that dodgy option for printing, why not print the data yourself using the `PrintDocument` class that is part of WinForms? You then have complete control where each bit of text goes with pixel precision, whatever the font.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable suggestion. And Now I change the font of the text file to "Courier New" and  using the `code`file.Write(ListBox2.Items(l_index).ToString().PadRight(30))`code` solved the problem. But if you have any better piece of code for the same that will be highly appreciated.